# Subtract string in one cell from another which are comma separated in excel

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, substring

How can I subtract a comma separated string from another one in Excel?
I want to subtract, A1 and A2 from A3 .

```
A1 - Wed,Thu 
A2- Sun, Mon
A3- Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun
A4- Tue,Fri,Sat
```

I tried the following :-

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(A1,A3,1)),A3,RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-LEN(A1)))
```

But the output is not as what I wanted. 
PS :- The A4 answer is the desired answer and not the answer I got after writing the above formula.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming these values are delimited by ***comma-space***. If not then adjust the formula accordingly (or use a double substitute to get rid of spaces before changing commas to tags).

In `A4` try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE("<t><s>"&A3&", "&A2&", "&A1&"</s></t>",", ","</s><s>"),"//s[not(following::*=. or preceding::*=.)]"))
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

If `FILTERXML` does spark your interest, then have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) for more possibilities.

Comment: Just realized this is a duplicate. I'll leave the answer be for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function RemoveItems(BigString As String, LittleString As String) As String
    Dim Good As Boolean, L, B, arrB, arrL
    Application.Volatile
    arrB = Split(Replace(BigString, " ", ""), ",")
    If InStr(LittleString, ",") = 0 Then
        For Each B In arrB
            If LittleString = B Then
            Else
                RemoveItems = RemoveItems & "," & B
            End If
        Next B
    Else
        arrL = Split(Replace(LittleString, " ", ""), ",")
        For Each B In arrB
            Good = True
                For Each L In arrL
                    If L = B Then Good = False
                Next L
                If Good Then RemoveItems = RemoveItems & "," & B
        Next B
    End If

    If RemoveItems <> "" Then RemoveItems = Mid(RemoveItems, 2)
End Function
```

It will remove items from the first comma-separated-string that appear in the second comma-separated-string.  for example:

[image]

In your example, you would **nest** the calls:

```
=RemoveItems(RemoveItems(A3,A1),A2)
```

[image]

**NOTES:**

- this version will accept a single item as well as a LettleString
- this version removes spaces from the strings